# Do the usage of antiperspirants causes skin cancer or breast cancer

Tags: dermatology, side-effects, cancer, breast

I was going through few articles and it have been mentioned that continuous usage of antiperspirants results in skin cancer or breast cancer and if its true can it cause more side effects over a long term of usage.

- [Does Your Antiperspirant Cause Cancer?](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2007/09/20/does-your-antiperspirant-cause-breast-cancer.aspx)
- [Antiperspirant Safety: Should You Sweat It?](http://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/features/antiperspirant-facts-safety)

Comment: Can you please link some of those articles (if they are behind a paywall perhaps just the abstracts)? Thanks!

Comment: @Lucky I have included the links as you had asked and in the pages that the links refers to also contains few information regarding the chances of Alzheimer's disease by using antiperspirants also.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at it and I'm sure the links will be helpful for others who want to try to answer as well :-)

Comment: @Lucky Sure.. :-)

Comment: It's unlikely for anybody to be able to give you a accurate answer to this question - there are simply far too many variables to consider. For example, "genetics".