# Are there any side-effects for using deodorant daily?

Tags: deodorant

I use Park Avenue deodorants (generally *cool blue* & now using *leap*). I daily use it at my underarms after coming from bath; daily means daily. I normally have to go out for library, tuition etcetera; before going anywhere I use the deo as it helps to sweat less & prevent any odour. So, I apply deo after bath, before going somewhere.

But yesterday, I met my cousin, a medical correspondent, who noticed my using of deo after taking bath; she then warned not to use it daily as it would darken the underarm places & in severe conditions, it may even emanate infection, skin problems.

I really got shocked; but didn't pay heed as it was written in the back that it should be used after bath.

But really, is(are) there any side-effects of using deo daily that I should need to bother at? It is of dire need as it prevents all those stinky odour & sweatiness. But really should I be in problem for my daily use?

Comment: Do you mean antiperspirants?

Comment: Related: [Do the usage of antiperspirants causes skin cancer or breast cancer](http://health.stackexchange.com/q/3290/114)

Comment: @kenorb: I've named the products I'm using; that's it I know.

Comment: Check if they've Aluminium in it. See: [Is aluminum in pans, soda cans and antiperspirants correlated to Alzheimer's?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/18182/8014)

Comment: @kenorb: You meant to say whether the container of the deodorant is made up of aluminium or something else?

Comment: They're adding aluminium into all antiperspirants (as part of ingredients) and there is a controversy about this topic whether it's causing Alzheimer's or not. So it's up to you. Personally I've stopped using antiperspirants a long time ago once I've got the results which showed aluminium toxicity (so I could only guess what caused that). So I can't answer that, as many studies contradict each other, so it's not safe topic to talk about.

Comment: @kenorb: Yes, you're right & I think antiperspirants, I think, should need some physician's consultation or prescription. However, what I'm using is deodorant. I saw its contents as: Ethyl alcohol,propellent, Propylene Glycol, Diethyl Pthalate, Butylated Hydroxy Toluene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had never heard about what your cousin refers to. Most studies about the impact of deodorants that I have ever found were regarding its effect on patients undergoing radiation therapy for breast cancer.

Even then, there does not seem to exist any evidence that deodorant increases the risk of breast cancer, as seen [here](http://journals.lww.com/epidem/Fulltext/2013/01000/Deodorant_Use_and_Breast_Cancer_Risk.29.aspx):

> We found no evidence from the combined published studies that deodorant promotes development of breast cancer, despite in vitro evidence supporting the parabens hypothesis

This matter is also approached in a [French study](http://www.jle.com/fr/revues/bdc/e-docs/lutilisation_de_deodorants_antitranspirants_ne_constitue_pas_un_risque_de_cancer_du_sein_278737/article.phtml):

> Aucune étude prospective épidémiologique n’a, à ce jour,démontré cette hypothèse, mais l’angoisse générée par cesspéculations  pseudoscientifiques  amène  régulièrement  denombreuses patientes et femmes à questionner leur médecinsur l’innocuité d’utilisation de ces produits. (...) Au final, il semble possible d’affirmer que cette question neconstitue pas un problème de santé publique et qu’il apparaîtdonc inutile de poursuivre les recherches sur ce sujet.

Even at [Cancer.Gov](http://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/causes-prevention/risk/myths/antiperspirants-fact-sheet) they say:

> However, researchers at the National Cancer Institute (NCI), a part of the National Institutes of Health, are not aware of any conclusive evidence linking the use of underarm antiperspirants or deodorants and the subsequent development of breast cancer.

Overall, it seems safe to use deodorants. At least I haven't find any evidence otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Okay, I'm glad to hear that deos are safe. But do they darken my underarms?

Comment: All the information regarding deodorants darkening your underarms area come from the so-called beauty websites. I can not tell you, scientifically, that deodorants darken your underarms, although that is something that is quite popular in beauty websites. Some of these suggest deodorants which do not cause underarms darkening. I will not provide links, because I don't see beauty websites as a valid source for information.

Comment: I'm going with you; thanks for the assurance:)